# Plot several fitted curves on one plot with drm function

Tags: r, plot, drc

I'm trying to plot some data that has been fitted with the `drm()` function from the drc package in R. I want to have several curves in the same plot overlapping each other.

I can get one fitted curve and the rest un-fitted into one curve like this:

```
#This is only mock data to show the concept

library(drc)

CurveData1 <- c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,2,3,4,5,5.2,5.4, 5.5, 5.6)
CurveData2 <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,3,4,5,6,6.2,6.4, 6.5, 6.6)
CurveData3 <- c(3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,4,5,6,7,7.2,7.4, 7.5, 7.6)
Conc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

fit1 <- drm(CurveData1 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())


plot(fit1, col = "black")
lines(CurveData2, Conc, col = "orange", type = "b")
lines(CurveData3, Conc, col = "blue", type = "b")
```

However, when I try to get all of the fitted curves into the same plot, like this:

```
#This is only mock data to show the concept

library(drc)

CurveData1 <- c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,2,3,4,5,5.2,5.4, 5.5, 5.6)
CurveData2 <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,3,4,5,6,6.2,6.4, 6.5, 6.6)
CurveData3 <- c(3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,4,5,6,7,7.2,7.4, 7.5, 7.6)
Conc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

fit1 <- drm(CurveData1 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())
fit2 <- drm(CurveData2 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())
fit3 <- drm(CurveData3 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())

plot(fit1, col = "black")
lines(fit2, col = "orange", type = "b")
lines(fit3, col = "blue", type = "b")
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y) :
> 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Any idea why this occurs and how to get around it? Is it due to a limitation in the `lines()` function or in the `plot()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing the trick?

```
library(drc)
library(ggplot2)
CurveData1 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,2,3,4,5,5.2,5.4, 5.5, 5.6)))
CurveData2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,3,4,5,6,6.2,6.4, 6.5, 6.6)))
CurveData3 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(c(3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,4,5,6,7,7.2,7.4, 7.5, 7.6)))
CurveData1$type = '1'
CurveData2$type = '2'
CurveData3$type = '3'
Conc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
all = rbind(CurveData1,CurveData2,CurveData3)
all$conc = rep(Conc,3)
  
ggplot(all, aes(x = conc, y = V1, col = type))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = drm, method.args = list(fct = LL.5()), se = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a really neat solution. Unfortunately I have to use the drm() function, which Pauls answer below solves. But this is also useful to know, thanks!:)

Comment: Turns out this solution was much more versatile after some modifications, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do not run into an error if I use only `plot` and `add = TRUE`. Moreover, if you look at `?plot.drc` you will find how to use the `plot()` function with `drc` objects.

```
  library(drc)

CurveData1 <- c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,2,3,4,5,5.2,5.4, 5.5, 5.6)
CurveData2 <- c(2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3,3,4,5,6,6.2,6.4, 6.5, 6.6)
CurveData3 <- c(3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3,4,5,6,7,7.2,7.4, 7.5, 7.6)
Conc <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

fit1 <- drm(CurveData1 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())
fit2 <- drm(CurveData2 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())
fit3 <- drm(CurveData3 ~ Conc, fct = LL.5())

plot(fit1)
plot(fit2, add = TRUE, col = "orange")
plot(fit3, add = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! Also, thank you for clarifying how to look it up myself, I tried to google but didn't find anything (to my knowledge at least). :)